# Migrate code from TFS to GITHUB with history

Tags: github-for-windows

I was looking at options to migrate code from TFS to GIT.
Has anyone tried this and can help me with this?

I am using this below command to migrate from TFS code branch to a local git repository.
This gives me an error saying invalid port number, name or credentials(Giving my credentials dint help either).

Command used in Git shell : Git tfs clone “http://tfs2012af004.intel.com:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/PMC/_versionControl#path=%24%2FPMC%2FPOCs%2FAGSVerificationConsoleForRoles&_a=contents” $/C:/Project/POC/Ramya

If any of you have already tried this, can you give me the command that you had used to migrate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution the URL that I was using was incorrect.

The command that worked is :
git tfs clone   $/
Eg : git tfs clone https://tfs-fm-04.devtools.intel.com/tfs/DefaultCollection  $/PMC/Test1

If we just specify the Project path with --b=all , all the branches of that project would be cloned
Eg : git tfs clone https://tfs-fm-04.devtools.intel.com/tfs/DefaultCollection  $/PMC/Test1 . --b=all